# Recommendations for kids sites

Tags: teaching

I am a teacher, and don’t really play much. My students like chess and I want to send them to some safe chess sites for kids. Recommendations?

Answer (score 3):

I have a few.

[Chess Kid](https://www.chesskid.com/) is part of chess.com, which is the largest chess site in the world. There are both free and paid memberships.

Another great site is [ChessKids Academy](http://www.chesskids.org.uk/). They have come very basic lessons for newcomers, and the best thing is that it is free.

[Kid Chess](https://www.kidchess.com/play-chess/) also has some nice material that is free.

All of these sites have components for both the players, and the adults, who are helping them.